# Import a Definition file to Amazon MQ through Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, rabbitmq, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-mq

I have created an Amazon MQ broker (with engine type RabbitMQ) using Terraform. now I want to import a definition file which is an XML.
This can be easily done manually, I just need to export the definition file and import it manually to AWS MQ.
but I need to automate this process using terraform. Any suggestion would be appreciated.
that is my terraform code:

```
resource "aws_mq_broker" "rabbitmq_broker" {
broker_name         = "mq_test"
engine_type         = var.mq_engine_type
engine_version      = var.mq_engine_version
host_instance_type  = var.mq_instance_type
deployment_mode     = var.mq_deployment_mode
security_groups     = [aws_security_group.ecs_private.id]
apply_immediately   = "true"
publicly_accessible = "false"
subnet_ids          = [aws_subnet.private.id]

user {
console_access = "true"
username       = var.mq_username
password       = "password"
}
tags = {
env         = "${terraform.workspace}",
 }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Do you have any terraform code?

Comment: So what is the issue with the code you have?

Comment: I want to impart definition file from another server ( explained in my question)

Comment: Which argument is used to provide the definition file?

Comment: looking for a solution. so far haven't find anything

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create an [MQ Configuration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/mq_configuration), which is what you pass the XML file to. Then you pass the configuration to the broker.

```
resource "aws_mq_configuration" "rabbitmq_broker_config" {
  name           = "My Broker Configuration"
  description    = "My RabbitMQ Broker Configuration"
  engine_type    = var.mq_engine_type
  engine_version = var.mq_engine_version

  data = file("${path.module}/broker-config.xml")
}

resource "aws_mq_broker" "rabbitmq_broker" {
  # All your attributes here
     
  configuration {
    id       = aws_mq_configuration.rabbitmq_broker_config.id
    revision = aws_mq_configuration.rabbitmq_broker_config.latest_revision
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is almost there, in this code you are create an MQ Configuration using a file, however, the real question is "How to import a definition" which is usually done by adding something like this to the configuration file
```
definitions.import_backend = local_filesystem
definitions.local.path = /path/to/definitions/defs.json
```
the question is how Amazon MQ can find such file with the definitions if the operation occur on the AWS side

Comment: @HectorManuel that would never happen on the AWS side. This is always going to happen on whatever computer is running Terraform.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what do you mean, could you maybe clarify this for me:

1. The configuration defined via Terraform (yes, that operation will locate the config file in the filesystem) and apply it, therefore I agree is only on Terraform side. 

2. Inside the configuration file, there is a section to "import definitions" that occurs on RabbitMQ node boot, therefore the "definitions" must be accessible to the node, hence it occurs on AWS side, and as far as I know, AWS doesn't provide any type of S3 or filesystem integration for that to occur